# Is there any way to teleport to a person in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, teleportation

If I am familiar with a person, but either don't know where they are or aren't familiar enough with their location to *[teleport](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/teleport.html)* there, is there any method of teleporting to the person rather than his or her location?

Comment: [Related.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47823/15469)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way would be to [scry](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/scrying.html#scrying) on your target.  Simple cast a scrying spell, and you can see the area immediately around the subject.  Since you can see the area, it counts as "studied carefully" for the purposes of Teleport, which makes it pretty easy to get there.  Since you're familiar with them, they get a -5 to the will save, assuming they don't want you to see them.