# If you are a willing target, do you decline your save or do you just not get one

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, saving-throw

When playing 3.x we've always played that the willing target of a spell can decline their saving throw and allow a spell to affect them automatically.  Recently a comment was posted on an answer of mine reading:

> Yeah, we're talkin' about protection from evil, which says that "the subject immediately receives another saving throw (if one was allowed to begin with)," yet when the spell marionette possession was cast the target was not allowed a saving throw because the target was willing when the spell targeted the creature!

This makes it matter in quite a few situations whether or not a willing target declines to take a saving throw to which they are entitled or whether willing targets are just not allowed saving throws in the first place.  Which is correct?

a 3.5 example is the 1st-level Clr spell resurgence [conju] (SpC 174-5), which says: "The subject of a resurgence spell can make a second attempt to save against an ongoing spell," presuming the creature made a first.

Comment: Where does *Protection from Evil* says anything about "the subject immediately receives another saving throw"? Looking at the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/protectionFromEvil.htm) I see it simply says it blocks any possession/domination/etc. effects

Comment: @G0BLiN Oh, that's the 3.5 SRD. The Pathfinder SRD is [here](https://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/protectionFromEvil.html#protection-from-evil). I assumed the OP was looking for Pathfinder rules, even though he mentioned 3.X and put the dnd-3.5e tag.

Comment: I'm looking for both, hence both tags.  I assume the answer is probably the same given the similarities between the systems but if not that's important.

Comment: There is a difference - PF's *Protection from Evil* grants an additional save, while 3.5's simply block or suppress the domination effect. So, this seems like a non issue in 3.x, but possibly a problem for PF (personally, I think disallowing the second save in PF is dubious, might add an answer explaining that if I have the time)

Comment: @G0BLiN ...This question is not about Protection from Evil.  What makes you think that it is?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer - maybe I focused too much on the quoted text... sorry if I'm diverting too far from the main issue. I can't think of another example where declining an allowed save or just not getting one makes such a difference - and the way I read PfE, it seems this case is moot (definitely so in 3.5, I think also in PF...). The questions is clear as is, but maybe adding other examples will help making it more concrete.

Comment: The 1st-level Clr spell *resurgence* [conju] (*SpC* 174-5), one of my favorite *3.5e* spells, says, "The subject of a *resurgence* spell can make a second attempt to save against an ongoing spell," presuming the creature made a first. Would this make a good *3.5e* example?

Answer (score 9):

Magic (CRB):

> **Voluntarily Giving up a Saving Throw**: A creature can voluntarily forego a saving throw and willingly accept a spell's result. Even a character with a special resistance to magic can suppress this quality.

If the creature is a willing target, they forego the saving throw: in other words they choose to fail it. You can do this at any time, for any spell, even the ones that don't ask for a willing participant (although it is rare to willingly fail against a harmful spell).

I don't really understand your entire question. If the subject of Marionette Possession was a willing target initially, and are then targeted by Protection from Alignment, why wouldn't they choose to fail the reroll, too? In any case, yes, that quote is technically false. Willing creatures get a saving throw (unless the spell says otherwise).

That's the RAW.

I suppose there is some ambiguity with the word *forego*. Some might argue that it means "refuse" or "bypass", and not "surrender" or "yield".

But I think it's pretty clear what the RAI is. And my experience, from what I've read online and heard from other players and GMs, supports this idea. It's also a common (house?) rule that a creature can choose to purposely fail *any* save, not just against spells.

Comment: Not sure where the quote in the question about "if [a save] was allowed to begin with" comes from - but it seems that with either interpretation, a save was *allowed*...

Comment: When this answer "suppose[s] there is some ambiguity with the word forego," it's correct that there is, but I don't see how the answer saying that "it's pretty clear what the RAI is" matters in this rules-as-written question. Likewise, although  what's been "read online and heard from other players and GMs, supports this idea," and that "[i]t's also a common (house?) rule that a creature can choose to purposely fail any save, not just against spells" makes no difference to the rules-as-written. With that in mind, I'm struggling to see how one definition of *forgo* is more valid than another!

Comment: @Umbranus It's not in the conditions glossary, it's in the [spell targeting rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell): "Some spells restrict you to willing targets only. [...] Unconscious creatures are automatically considered willing."

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, I can't see how you would fail a Fortitude save against, say, poison. It's not like you can tell your body to stop fighting...

Comment: @BgrWorker Poison might be one of those exceptions. That and illusions. The (house?) rule of intentional failure should be used only when it makes sense. Reflex? Just don't move. Fort vs disease? Roll in that infectious goo. Will vs mind control? Relax.

Comment: Note that creatures that are immune cannot voluntarily lower their immunity, iirc.

Comment: @nijineko Covered adequately by this [question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70850/8610). In short, one sentence in the whole game says that a creature can lower an immunity (*PH* 177), and the concept goes unmentioned by the remainder of the game. Make of that what you will.

Comment: Wow, nice round-about on that one. No wonder it is hard to pick up.

Answer (score 5):

On [Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic) on [Aiming a Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) on Target or Targets discusses how a target becomes willing:

> Some spells restrict you to willing targets only. Declaring yourself as a willing target is something that can be done at any time (even if you're flat-footed or it isn't your turn). Unconscious creatures are automatically considered willing, but a character who is conscious but immobile or helpless (such as one who is bound, cowering, grappling, paralyzed, pinned, or stunned) is not automatically willing.

I don't think it's controversial to say that, typically, a creature that opts to make a saving throw then rolls the die then determines the saving throw's result, be that result a natural 1, 2–19 plus the creature's modifiers, or a natural 20.

That said, Magic on [Saving Throws](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Saving-Throw) on Voluntarily Giving up a Saving Throw only says, "A creature can voluntarily forgo a saving throw and willingly accept a spell's result." This seems to leave but two choices about the meaning of the phrase *voluntarily forgo*. These are put into context below:

1. A creature *makes a saving throw yet picks a result that fails* to willingly accept a spell's result.
2. A creature *doesn't make* a saving throw to willingly accept a spell's result.

Such a subtle distinction is rarely needed, but when it is, this GM leans toward #2. That's because the remainder of the game makes it clear—on [attack rolls](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attack-Roll), for instance, and on [skill checks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Skill-Checks1)—that any attempt the GM allows a typical creature to make has the *possibility* of success, whether due to a natural 20 or to modifiers that the creature isn't aware of, and whether the creature actually *wants* to succeed or not.<sup>1</sup> And, while a creature can impose upon itself penalties sufficient so that failure is *almost* certain, the creature's failure—if it makes the attempt at all—is not *assured*.

The only real way to have *no* chance of success is *not to make the attempt*. To paraphrase Yoda, in this GM's campaigns it's *try or try not—there is no do and pick the result.*

> #### Example for [dnd3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd3.5e)
>
> Creature A that's suffering emotional trauma due to its recent dental torture (don't ask) urges Creature B to cast on it the 3rd-level Clr spell *heart's ease* [conj] (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 100). Creature B casts the spell, Creature A voluntarily forgoes its saving throw, and the spell's effect ensues.
>
> Ten years later, Creature A decides it no longer needs the effect of that *heart's ease* spell and urges Creature B to cast on it the 1st-level Clr spell *resurgence* [conju] (*Spell Compendium* 174-5), which says, "The subject of a *resurgence* spell can make a second attempt to save against
>   an ongoing spell."<sup>2</sup> Creature B explains to Creature A that *resurgence* won't work, Creature A having never made the *first* saving throw against the spell *heart's ease*, but Creature B's happy to use an effect like [*dispel magic*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#dispel-magic) instead.
>
> #### Example for [pathfinder](/questions/tagged/pathfinder)
>
> Creature A that's [sleeping](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2knrt?Sleep#5) (therefore equivalent to [unconscious](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Unconscious) therefore willing) is targeted by Creature B's [*marionette possession*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/marionette-possession) spell. The spell has the entry *Target: One willing creature* and the [printed version](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2m8o8&page=9?Ultimate-Magic-Errata#421) the entry *Saving Throw: Will negates*. (The saving throw entry's parenthetical *see below* is unmentioned by the spell's description.) Creature A *is* willing so, in this GM's campaign, Creature A makes no saving throw as it's a willingly target of the spell *marionette possession*.<sup>3</sup>
>
> Later, Creature C casts on Creature A—still affected by the spell *marionette possession*—the spell *protection from evil*, which allows "the subject… [to make] another saving throw (if one was allowed to begin with) against any spells or effects that possess or exercise mental control over the creature." However, this GM would rule that the Creature A—if awake and not willing—is *not* allowed *another* saving throw against the spell *marionette possession* as Creature A wasn't allowed a saving throw to begin with!<sup>4</sup>

There's an argument saying that, essentially, a creature is in absolute control of its results *if* those results would typically seem to be less than optimal.<sup>5</sup> That is, a GM may allow a Str 10 Medium creature to deal with its [dagger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/dagger) 1d3, 1d2, or 1 point of damage; or allow a creature to declare its attack roll a 1; or allow a creature to pick the result of its saving throw—even against poison or disease!—as long as the result is failure. That's absolutely an *attractive* and *fun* position, but this GM finds no support for it in the rules.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49312/8610) discusses voluntary failure specifically.
<sup>**2**</sup> One of my players pointed out the disturbing and darkly amusing duration of the spell *heart's ease*, which is merely permanent rather than the expected instantaneous. One can, using the spell *heart's ease*, torture a creature more by first ridding it of the mental anguish caused by its torture *then bring flooding back all that mental anguish!* There are some *messed up* spells in the *Book of Exalted Deeds*!
<sup>**3**</sup> By the way, the spell *marionette possession* would've failed outright had it been cast on an *unwilling* creature.
<sup>**4**</sup> The spell *marionette possession* says first, "You project your soul out of your body and into the body of a willing creature," then immediately after says, "This possession is blocked by *protection from evil* or a similar ward." The former spell doesn't again reference the latter, making it the GM's option whether the spell *protection from evil* can have any effect on the spell *marionette possession* after the spell *marionette possession* is cast. This author has assumed the example's GM entertained the more upbeat notion.
<sup>**5**</sup> Just an aside: [taking 10 and taking 20](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Taking-10-and-Taking-20) are *not* a check's results but substitutes for die rolls. The check's *result* is 10, 20, or the die roll *plus modifiers*, and a creature may be unaware of some modifiers until or unless the GM *reveals* the result!

Comment: So for you voluntarily forgoing a die roll counts as not having been allowed to make one?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Not necessarily, but being a willing target means the target wasn't allowed to make a saving throw against the effect. The creature has willingly accepted the spell's result rather than tried and failed to resist the spell's effect. (Much like a creature about to be slain by its foes may *either* suffer the consequences for not making a Diplomacy skill check *or* risk making the check and possibly fail. The destination's the same, but the journey's different.)